# Bring popup to front

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my application, I have a popup with information that open when I choose some options.

First time it's OK, popup highlights in front of everything.

But, when it loses focus, when the user goes to other window, if user clicks again in the same option, I want that the popup shows up again, in front of everything.

I tried something like:

```
<body onLoad="this.focus()">
window.focus();   
document.focus();  
this.focus();
```

but it does not work for me.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should maintain a reference to the popup window you open and call focus method on it.

```
var win = window.open(url, name, args);
win.focus();
```

While opening a popup if you give a name and next time when you open a popup with the same name it will use the same popup if it is not closed. You just have to focus it.

You can use this simple function to handle popups

```
function windowOpener(url, name, args) {

    if(typeof(popupWin) != "object" || popupWin.closed)  { 
        popupWin =  window.open(url, name, args); 
    } 
    else{ 
        popupWin.location.href = url; 
    }

    popupWin.focus(); 
 }
```

Comment: i'm testing right now and look's like a good solution, works fine in chrome and ie, but in FF is acting strange. Dont know how to explain to you, but when i open the popup (using `windowOpener`) and then open another one, from a diferent click source, if i click to the popup that have `windowOpener`, him self dont focus in front of everything, this only happen in FF.