# jquery open window but only when window is not opened already; then show it in front of other windows?

Tags: jquery, popup

Would it be possible to have on click div open a window but only if that window hasn't opened before? Not modal but just a regular window with a certain size say 300x300.

I have this Jsfiddle but not fully working yet. The idea is to have 1 popup window and just push it in the front if its already opened.

http://jsfiddle.net/BC9Rd/

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9009074/219118

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$("#element_id").click(function(){
  window.open ("http://your-domain.com/your-url.html","my_window","menubar=1,resizable=1,width=350,height=250");
});
```

Basically every time you execute this window.open command, the same window will be utilized because of the same window name ("my_window" in this case)...

I hope this helps :)