# Inline javascript for window.open

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I have a problem. I want to open a window onclick of a link with a condition that it is not already opened. something like this.

```
function openPopupOneAtATime() {
    if (popup && !popup.closed) {
        popup.focus();
    }
    else {
        popup = window.open("http://www.google.com", 'window');
        return false;
    }
}
```

i do not want to write this in a function . i want to write an inline onclick event checking this if condition .. something like this

```
onclick="if (popup && !popup.closed){("http://www.google.com",'window')}"
```

i will declare a javascript variable

```
var popup;
```

If a window is already open and we try to open a new window with the same name, **the browser reloads** the page inside the same window. i donot want that thing to happen.if a window with that name is already open. either give focus to that window or do nothing. The code is working fine if i write it in terms of function and call the function onclick , but i want this thing to be inline.

Comment: This might be an approach:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250591/jquery-open-window-but-only-when-window-is-not-opened-already-then-show-it-in-f

Answer (score -1):

For starters: this has nothing to do with jQuery.

Why would you want to inline the code in the onclick? inlining javascript events is bad practice

for an article on how to do this: google is your friend! http://www.idocs.com/tags/linking/linking_famsupp_89.html